# Displaying text with DirectX 9 crashes after several calls

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I want to display text with DirectX 9 but after thousands of calls the application crashes. In the future the text should be changeable, but in the example below, the text is everytime the same. The stack trace gives not much information, the crash occurs in some other part of the program due an access violation.

The header:

```
(...)

class QD3DWidget;

class D3DText : public D3DPrimitive
{

  public:
    D3DText(IDirect3DDevice9 * device);
    virtual ~D3DText();

    virtual bool CreateBuffers();
    virtual void ReleaseBuffers();
    virtual void Draw();

  protected:
    IDirect3DDevice9 * Device();

  private:

    struct TextData {
        Vector2 pos;
        std::string text;
    };

    QD3DWidget * m_pQD3DWidget;
    IDirect3DDevice9 * m_pD3DDevice;
    ID3DXFont *font;

};
#endif
```

And the implementation:

```
(...)

D3DText::D3DText(IDirect3DDevice9 * device)
    : D3DPrimitive(device),
    m_pQD3DWidget(0),
    m_pD3DDevice(device),
    font(0)
{
}

D3DText::~D3DText()
{
    ReleaseBuffers();
}

void D3DText::Draw()
{
    if (font)
    {
        RECT fRectangle;
        SetRect(&fRectangle, 0, 0, 1000, 440);
        std::string message = "This is some generic message to\ndisplay on the screen";
        font->DrawTextA(NULL, message.c_str(), -1, &fRectangle, DT_LEFT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0));
    }
}

void D3DText::ReleaseBuffers()
{
    if (font) { 
        font->Release(); font = 0; 
    }
}

bool D3DText::CreateBuffers()
{
    font = 0;
    HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateFont(m_pD3DDevice, 22, 0, FW_NORMAL, 1, false, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Arial"), &font);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return false;
    
    return true;
}

IDirect3DDevice9 * D3DText::Device()
{
    return m_pD3DDevice;
}
```

Comment: *"the crash occurs in some other part of the program due an access violation"* Why would it be related to the minimal and a priori inoffensive piece of code you show, then? Please post a reproducible code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The crash is produced by the code shown above. If I remove the code in the methods, the crash disappears.

Comment: ***if I remove the code in the methods, the crash disappears.*** That does not mean that the code shown is the cause. Some code earlier could have corrupted the heap. And without this code the corruption does not cause a crash.